# opencv, compiling xfeatures2d

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, clang

I'm trying to add extra modules for opencv from https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib . I followed instructions an after generate, i got this:

OpenCV modules:

To be built:   core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d aruco video bgsegm ml objdetect ocl bioinspired ccalib legacy photo gpu nonfree contrib face text datasets dnn dpm fuzzy line_descriptor plot python reg rgbd saliency stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching tracking ts videostab xobjdetect photo

Disabled:                    world contrib_world ximgproc

**Disabled by dependency:      optflow xfeatures2d**

Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda java viz cvv hdf matlab sfm

I need xfeatures2d, how can i fix it? I'm on OS X

Answer (score 0):

From what I've just checked in OpenCV's cmake files, the xfeatures2d module depends on the *shape* module, which is not listed in your modules to be built.
Since there are no more errors given, I'm only guessing this might cause your problem. Try to enable it.

Anyways, if you don't have to explicitly build it manually, you could use [homebrew](http://brew.sh).

To install OpenCV3 with contrib modules:

```
brew install homebrew/science/opencv3 --with-contrib
brew link opencv3 --force
```